# Need Anchors for Pre-cast Concrete Panel with Insulation Inside

Tags: structural-engineering

I am looking for a solution for mounting a shelf that holds a pressure sprayer to precast Concrete panel with a Foam core insulation sandwiched in the middle.   total weight to support is 300 pounds, The shelf has 6 holes to mount with located in 2 rows of 3. The panel is  8 inch total (3 inches then 2-inch foam panel then 3 inches). ( diameter of holes in Shelf is 1/2 inch so I think 3/8 inch anchors are appropriate.  If anyone could send a link to a product that would be great.   Engineering data / Submittal type info would be very helpful as well.   I need to validate that the ANchors are appropriate for precast concrete.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: A diagram is needed.

Comment: The biggest concern is vibration from the pump. Is it a standard three cylinder pump that runs about 2500 psi or so? The do-it-once solution is to bore six holes right through, then bog in six steel compression tubes that are about 1/8 shorter than the wall thickness, then hang a 1/4 backing plate and through bolt the thing. Don't underestimate what vibration can do to the mounts. How many thousand hours/yr does the pump run?

Comment: Thank you for this information,   I never thought of it this way,    So currently the Shelf does have 6 holes to mount thru,  I spec'd out  Screw Anchors that are 3 inches long,   We cannot go all the way to the exterior and mount a bracket like you suggested, but that is a great idea.    That said, these anchors are rated to almost 7000 LB  for tension and shear forces- each when fixed to a 3-inch concrete panel.

Answer (score 1):

This is a situation that should be reviewed by a structural engineer. More about preventing damage to the panel then about support of the item.

For anchor information, check out [Simpson Mechanical Anchors](https://www.strongtie.com/mechanicalanchoringproducts_anchoringsystems/category). The Titen HD is a common choice

Comment: Thank you for the link and suggesting  that an engineer review,  that's what we ended up doing,  and the link has very useful information about the options for selecting anchors.